# Почему не работает определение имени?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, join, login

Пишу терминальную игрушку по угадыванию числа. Когда вводишь имя пользователя, даже если оно есть в словаре, он пишет, что новый пользователь сохранен и просто перезаписывает очки....
Вот код:

```
#*** Поиск и запись пользователя в базу ***
def Proverka(): #!
    global polsovatel
    global name
    global dic
    if name.find(polsovatel.name) != -1 : #Если имя пользователя есть в словаре начинаем игру
        print("Игра началась!")
    
    else:
        dic[polsovatel.name] = '0' #Если нет - добавляем
        print("Пользователь сохранен")
        print(dic)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Духсообщества, исправила.... вроде....

Comment: Не исправили. Информации все равно избыточно. Но попробую ответить. Судя по `if dic[key] >= 10` значением ключа у вас является число. Итерироваться можно только по спискам и строкам.

Comment: @Духсообщества, но при первом включении игры, а так же если в конце игры выбрать не "продолжить с этим же логином", а новое имя, то ошибки не всплывает....

Comment: @Духсообщества вы гений! Я понял!!!! И исправила!
А вы случайно не подскажете, как правильно сравнить строку, введенную пользователем не со значением ключа, а названием его?

Comment: Зачем вы переделали вопрос на другой? Если у вас есть другой вопрос - задавайте его отдельно. А то теперь все ответы не соответствуют вопросу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функцию строки [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) можно передавать только то, что можно итерировать (типа строк, списки, ...)
А у вас, судя по коду, там число.

Если вы хотите привести число к строке, то вместо:

```
scoreN = ("".join(dic[key]))
```

Используйте `str`:

```
scoreN = str(dic[key])
```

**UPD.**

Но, вообще, я не понимаю зачем вы приводили значение в `dic[key]` в строку, если после сразу же приводите эту строку в число, как видно тут:

```
scoreN = ("".join(dic[key]))
polsovatel.score = int(scoreN) + (int(n)-polsovatel.i)*2
scoreS = polsovatel.score - int(scoreN)
...
polsovatel.score = int(scoreN) - 10
```

Я бы код поменял так:

```
scoreN = dic[key]
polsovatel.score = scoreN + (n - polsovatel.i) * 2
scoreS = polsovatel.score - scoreN
...
polsovatel.score = scoreN - 10
```